# Can't import .sql file

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a 1.4GB .gz backup file(which is 8GB unzipped) I have to import to the server but it isnt working whatever method I have tried.

1st I tried Workbench, after 2 days and still no progress I canceled, and after some research I found out console was the better option with big files.

On Console I tried importing directly from compressed .gz however that gave me ascii\0 error so I unzipped and tried uploading the file directly. This time it started very fast with some occasional spikes (like some rows gets 0.8 secs but the next row 11.76 secs). But this time it got stuck at the last second. I tried this step with 4 different OS and hardware setups.(Vista,7 server 08 and ubuntu also I tried with dedicated hardware also)

Since the file is big I cant just open it from notepad++ and I read that might corrupt the file also.

I cant get a new backup as the data came from outside source.

The database has 15 coloumns, myISAM engine.

As I can't seem to find anything else I would like some help as to what might be causing this issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have lots of indexes?  And a tiny key_buffer_size?

Comment: If you want to open the file (good idea to eyeball your data), use vi (works on both Windows and Linux!

Comment: @RickJames, my key_buffer_size is: 2344M with a 8GB RAM machine. I used percona config wizard.

Comment: Do you know on what it is getting stuck? `show processlist` what's the output... Maybe you are getting stuck on `repair by keycache` because of small tmp dir

Comment: @CodeBird, This is the output;                                                                '1 | root | localhost:50828 | maindb | Query   | 1572 | Repair with keycache
          | /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `main` ENABLE KEYS */
                                 |
|  3 | root | localhost:51396 | NULL   | Query   | 1324 | Waiting for table meta
data lock | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHE
MA`='maindb' AND `TABLE_TYPE`='B |
|  4 | root | localhost:51455 | NULL   | Query   |    0 | init '

Comment: Your issue is that you have a small tmp dir which is forcing repair by keycache at the place of repair by sorting. Use a bigger tmp dir and your issue is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments above your issue comes from a small tmp dir. There are many answers on stackoverflow concerning this. Here is 1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067521/716691

And here's how to change mysql tmp dir temporarily without editing my.cnf. Make sure you create a tmp dir somewhere with enough available space.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853110/716691